# Using JOLT transform I need to extract only the content part from the JSON payload. need the JOLT SPEC

Tags: json, transform, jolt

```json
{
  "snippet-format": "empty-snippet",
  "total": 361,
  "start": 1,
  "page-length": 5,
  "selected": "include",
  "results": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "uri": "/DEV/xyz-xyzRecord/OS1.json",
      "path": "fn:doc(\"/SIT1/xyz-xyzRecord/AB1.json\")",
      "score": 0,
      "confidence": 0,
      "fitness": 0,
      "href": "/v1/documents?uri=%2FDEV%2FIxyz-xyzRecord%2FOS1.json&database=data-hub-DEV",
      "mimetype": "application/json",
      "format": "json",
      "matches": null,
      "extracted": {
        "kind": "array",
        "content": [
          {
            "xyz": "AB1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output is

```json
[
  {
    "xyz": "AB1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@results[0].extracted.content": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Another option might be

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "results": {
        "*": {
          "extracted": {
            "content": {
              "*": "[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```